# Invalid resource type in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am having the following issue:

> Invalid resource type msql::db at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp:6

My manifest (db.pp) is:

```
include mysql::server

msql::db { "loja":
  schema   => "loja_schema",
  password => "lojasecret",
}
```

My defined type called mysql::db is in a module called **mysql**. This module has a manifest folder with **init.pp**:

```
class mysql { }
```

And a file called **db.pp** where the defined type is:

```
define mysql::db($schema, $user = $title, $password) {
  #Dependência
  Class['mysql::server'] -> Mysql::db[$title]

  exec { "$title-schema":
    unless  => "mysql -uroot $schema",
    command => "mysqladmin -uroot create $schema",
    path  => "/usr/bin/",
  }

  exec {"$title-user":
    unless  => "mysql -u$user -p$password $schema",
    command => "mysql -uroot -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \
                                  $schema.* TO '$user'@'%' \
                                  IDENTIFIED BY '$password';\"",
    path    => "/usr/bin/",
    require => Exec["$title-schema"],
  }
}
```

What it seems to be problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You typed msql::db, that is probably a typo.

I think you probably meant mysql::db.